Getting error at @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Auto)
enter image description hereThe type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type jakarta.persistence.GenerationType  showing at package
i want to resolve my error.i tried so many times but no use anyone help me..

Post your classes and error logs in question
